# Volume Mixer notifcation sound on volume change xubuntu

Tags: sound, xubuntu, notification

I'm running xubuntu 16.04, and I have noticed something strange. Whenever I change the volume, there is no tone that sort of lets me know how loud it is. It makes me think that my sound is not working when it is. I have to go to youtube or something just to confirm.

I tried looking aorund but it seems like a strange problem so it's hard to find. Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Okay so I made some progress.. When I open the sound settings, it makes a notification sound (after installing sox & gnome-session-canberra), but when I use the one on the panel no sound, any ideas?

Comment: The sound notifications will work from within the default PulseAudio sound settings (`pavucontrol`) even without installing `sox` and `gnome-session-canberra`. I can confirm this. The problem is with how Xubuntu handles notifications from the system tray. Check [this](https://askubuntu.com/q/928508/700539) related question. I think it is a bug in the distro. Can you please tell me if you see the brightness indicator notification when you try to change the brightness from the notification panel by **scrolling** with your mouse (not by keyboard shortcut or dragging buttons within the applet)?

Answer (score 0):

Using UbuntuGnome I can find it in the gnome-control-center choosing the audio settings and the register Sound Effects. Be sure to have them enabled as well a s their volume should not be set to 0.

[image]

Comment: Okay so I made some progress.. When I open the sound settings, it makes a notification sound (after installing sox & gnome-session-canberra), but when I use the one on the panel no sound, any ideas?

Comment: In `gnome-control-center`  tab Output (or Ausgabe in the above pic) there should be a button Test Speakers.

Comment: @starkus `gnome-control-center` is NOT supported in Xubuntu. The dependencies are broken.