# Notifications Alert Sound on Xubuntu 16.04

Tags: sound, xubuntu, notification

This is the same problem from [6 years ago](https://askubuntu.com/questions/86502/re-enable-popping-sounds) and [5 years ago](https://askubuntu.com/questions/96012/notification-alert-sounds-do-not-work). Let me quote the linked question.

> I have sound working and I have the Login Sound working but I don't
>   get any other alert/notification sounds. E.g. if a question box pops
>   up - there's no sound.

The 6-year-old solution (compiz configuration) doesn't work for me. The one provided 5 years ago (using Ubuntu tweak) is outdated and particularly not suited for Xfce. I have figured that it has probably something to do with the fact that `beep` doesn't work on my system. Neither does `echo -e "\a"` succeed in producing any audible sound. However, the PulseAudio command line interface works pretty well. I can do something like `paplay path/to/audio/file.ogg` to produce a sound from a bash script, for example.

However, the problem is that notifications from some applications don't work using PulseAudio. Therefore, they go unheard most of the times.

What should I do? Why hasn't there been any improvement since six years?

---

**EDIT:**

1. I noticed that even the login sound does not work for me.
2. I updated the following values in the system settings.

   [image: settings editor]

   For this to work properly, I installed `gnome-session-canberra, ubuntu-sounds, sox, xfconf`, without one bit of progress.
3. I tried adding the following to autostart. No success here as well!

   [image: indicator sound]
4. Heck I reinstalled the entire `xubuntu-desktop` to see if I messed something up. But it hasn't improved the situation one bit.

I am still missing important notification sounds. Many apps (for example, email clients such as `nylas-mail`) cannot even send notifications. I am starting to think that this is a bug in the Xubuntu distro itself. Should I report this bug? Or can I fix this?

Comment: related (unanswered) but not a duplicate: https://askubuntu.com/q/911924/700539

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I do not think your description is accurate. I could reproduce the following with a fresh install of Xubuntu 16.04.

1. Changing of volume does not involve any sound notifications.
2. Changing brightness by *scrolling* on the battery icon does not show any indicator notification. However, changing it by means of a keyboard does trigger a notification.

Please purge `Nylas Mail` (or the likes) and reinstall to check if notifications are still mute. In my case, they weren't.

In summary, you could register your problems probably as [feature requests](https://wiki.xfce.org/wish_list) or [bug reports](https://docs.xubuntu.org/contributors/qa-bugs.html) (I am not sure which is appropriate). Alternatively, you can ask a question here regarding however you want to manually customise your notification preferences. Be specific about what you want.

Comment: I wonder if it is like that by design. Anyway, I think I can live with these limitations for now, given that all other important notifications are working perfectly.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem and solved it last night by following these directions I found on Ubuntu forums(they won't let me add an image) ... https://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=1869787 ... also I see you have not named your "sound theme name" in Settings Editor - X Settings. And be sure to check dconf Editor - org.gnome.desktop.sound and make sure event sounds & input-feedback-sounds are checked and theme name is correct (in this case ubuntu). I had to add theme sound twice before everything worked but it works now :) This would of been much easier and more informative if I was allowed to post screenshots .. Sorry and good luck to you, let me know if this works.